# How to get Opened file path in VSTO Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I have a plug-in written in VSTO C#. I'm reading excel rows using Microsoft Interop and I need to use this plug-in for large excel files. Microsoft Interop is bit slow while reading data. I want to use other library to read the data but for this I need to have opened excel file path. I tried to find a way but I was unable to find any way to get the opened excel file. Is there any way to get the path of excel opened file using vsto plug-in?

Comment: So you're not using Excel-DNA?

Comment: I'm using excel dna

Answer (score 0):

The [Workbook.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.path) property returns a string that represents the complete path to the workbook/file that this workbook object represents. Note, if a workbook has never been saved, its `Path` property returns an empty string ("").

You may also find the [Workbook.Saved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saved) property helpful which returns `true` if no changes have been made to the specified workbook since it was last saved.